# maven clean install fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have this spring boot application that I need to build. but it fails for some reason that I couldn’t find by myself. I need to host this on heroku as well. Please can someone help me on this? my spring boot knowledge is not good.

It says the column is not found.I checked for thee typos as well.

[image]

Here's the source code. https://github.com/anjula-sack/scholarx `cannot find symbol`
Here's the build log. https://pastebin.com/15zkVP22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the Spring Data JPA dependency in your POM:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

That's why there's a lot of "package javax.persistence... does not exist" in your log and this is causing your build to fail, since not all dependencies are set.